# Can I still get the Pacifist achievement if an NPC accidentally commits suicide?

Tags: achievements, deus-ex-human-revolution

Here I am playing on the hardest setting and trying to get the pacifist achievement also. I *just* finished the "Black Hawk Down" scene when you arrive back in Hengsha. After 5 MILLION retries I finally downed all the enemies non-lethally, and got the robot without any "collateral damage" or accidental kills. But...there's one guy who shoots a barrel that he's standing next to right at the beginning of my save.

Here's the question:

Does that guy count against my no kill record? Am I disqualified from the Pacifist achievement because of something the computer did? Would it be "safer" to just reload from an earlier point?

Comment: Don't kill anyone?

Comment: @Ian Thanks. But, seriously. He shot the barrel, and the barrel killed him. So, what do you call that?

Comment: It's safer not to save Malik if you are going for Pacifist. If you want the achievement for saving her, just make a save before the scene, save her and then reload.

Comment: By the way, if the robot kills anyone by self-destructing on its own, you still keep Pacifist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the wiki page:

http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Pacifist

I think incompetent AI may affect the achievement. I would rather be safe than sorry and make a save just before the shooting starts and go stealthy to the elevator. If your going for the saving Malik achievement go back to the save you made earlier and use lethal weaponry.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify, you don't actually have to save Malik to get the Pacifist achievement. So you can just run past all the guards and go into the elevator, without any risk of discounting the achievement.

But to your question, this does count against the pacifist achievement.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm pretty sure it doesn't, I mean he killed himself, you didn't have any control over it.

Comment: @MrSmooth I'm about 90% sure it does. I'll do some testing with it later tonight.

Comment: I agree that it's a bit overkill to want to save Malik on this particular run. But I'm already invested in doing it. The situation now is that no matter if I try to save her or not, this one security guard always shoots the exploding barrel he's behind and dies.Is there no clear-cut info on what ruins the Pacifist achievement? I just assumed that there'd be a rule in the strategy guides or something. If I have to go the entire game without one enemy dying accidentally this is going to be a major drag. I appreciate you're looking into it though!

Comment: @NoFairFights There's actually no real facts surrounding that subject, only speculations. So there's hard to know what counts and what not. But, I still believe I am correct. Almost all deaths happening in the game discounts the pacifist achievement, although there are a few exceptions, as boss fights. The saving Malik mission is a HUGE black area thought. As some of the mechanics that normally counts against the achievement, does not in this part. Example; if the explosion from the robot kills anyone, it will not discount the achievement, but outside that mission, it will.

Comment: However, I still believe the explosion from a barrel counts, even if you did not explode it. As I have tested this outside that mission before. However, I cannot be certain, since that mission is kinda weird. So I would recommend loading from an earlier point, and hopefully you won't be as unlucky next time :)

Comment: I'm reasonably sure this is wrong. Explosions from a robot self-destructing do not count toward Pacifist, so I don't think this does either. You can check yourself though, if you received XP for the kill, you're discounted for Pacifist.

Comment: @ArdaXi Actually, not receiving XP from a kill, does not mean it's not counted against the achievement. I've been discounted from the achievement even if I did not receive XP from an explosion kill.

Answer (score 0):

The guard with the barrel doesn't affect "pacifist" - that happened to me and I still got the achievement. 
Killing guards in the final boss fight does affect it even though it doesn't give the "man down" exp message - like the whole arctic level for me in fact, so be careful there too because you won't get the merciful soul message either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it would as the achievement states anyone "dying by your hand" so you could be safe but I don't think it would count against you.